# Bad access of memory - exception (C++)

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management

I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` on the 3rd last line where I return a *Bitvector. As you can see in the `main` I try to flip the 10'th index to 1. I highly suspect the way I manage my memory is the cause, but can't figure out where and how. (Note that the BinTree is not completed, I'm using a mac, and I use vs-code).

```
struct node {
    BitVector b;
    node* parent;
    node* right;
    node* left;
};

class BinTree {

    node* root;
    node* insert(node* t, int g) {
        if (t==NULL) {
            t->b.get_bitvector()->at(g) = 1; //Here I try to set the g'th index to be 1 in the bitvector.
        }
        return t;
}

public:
    BinTree() {
        root = NULL;
    }

    void insert(int g) {
        root = insert(root, g);
    }
};


class BitVector {
    vector<short>* bitvector; // construct a pointer
public:
    BitVector() {
        bitvector = new vector<short>(30); // point the pointer to a vector of size 30.
    }
    vector<short>* get_bitvector() {
        return bitvector; //Exception occurs here
    }
};



int main() {
    BinTree t;
    t.insert(10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` happens when you try to access memory which isn't allocated by the application; which the application has no access privilege to. 
I suppose the error is because your not adding nodes to your tree. Your just calling them. And over here: `if (t==NULL)`, `t->b.get_bitvector()->at(g)` is called only if the node address is `0x0`, hence the error.

What you should do is, make the logic to add a node if not found in some way and change `t==NULL` to `t!=NULL`.

Note: Try using `nullptr` and ditch `NULL` when working with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is failing at two points.

First, you have to check bintree->t for being NOT null:

```
if (t != NULL) {
            t->b.get_bitvector()->at(g) = 1; 
}
```

Second, you have to initialize your bintree->t with a bitvector instead of a NULL:

```
public:
    BinTree() {
        root = new BitVector();
    }
```